# inorder tree traversal saving the node's value when traversing

Tags: tree, tree-traversal

I have this piece of code to traverse a tree with "in-order" fashion.

However I just not sure what is wrong as it doesn't seem to store the corresponding node's value when the node is not NULL.

I have added various print statement around to check whether a node's value should be stored when the recursion is running. And from the print statement, it seems as long as the node is non-NULL, then their value should have been stored already. But somehow it is not the case when I run the following the store the tree's value in the vector nodesVal:

```
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        std::vector<int> nodesVal;
        int i = 0;  // initialize the position to check the element in the vector during recursion
        if(root!=0) {
            
            printf("value of root->val is %d\n", root->val);
            
            nodesVal.push_back(root->val);  // Did I not store the non-NULL node's value in this line here?  for every recursive call whether it is right, left child during the recursion?  so what is missing?
            
            printf("vector's value at position i:  %d\n", nodesVal[i]); 
            

            if(root->left) {
                i++;
                preorderTraversal(root->left);
            }
            if (root->right) {
                i++;
                preorderTraversal(root->right);
            }   
        }
        return nodesVal;
    }
```

This is the statements printed by cout:

```
value of root->val is 1
integer value 1           // this here output the vector's value at position 0 which indeed is value 1. So it seems correct. 

value of root->val is 2
integer value 2        // this here output the vector's value at position 1 which indeed is value 2. So it seems correct. 


value of root->val is 3
integer value 3            // this here output the vector's value at position 2 which indeed is shown to be 3
```

so the vector seems to be able to store the value as I checked the 0th, 1st, and 2nd position, but somehow it it not the case as the testcase of [1, NULL, 3,2] shows this is failing:

Below is a tree with root at 1, then no left child of 1, but there is a right
child of 1 which is 3. The child with label 3 also has a left child, but no right child.

```
        1
 null       3 
          2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the vector that is returned by the recursive call is ignored. All the collection that happened recursively is now lost and your local vector is still only having one entry.

When you look at the declaration of the local vector variable, and the `return` at the end of the function, you can see that the *only* thing that ever happens to it, is a *single* `push_back` call.

There are different ways to get it working:

1. Only have *one* vector, and pass it along as a by-reference argument.

   ```cpp
   void preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root, vector<int> &nodesVal) {
       if (root != nullptr) {            
           nodesVal.push_back(root->val);
           if (root->left) preorderTraversal(root->left, nodesVal);
           if (root->right) preorderTraversal(root->right, nodesVal);
       }
   }
   ```

   ...and the caller should then not expect the vector as return value, but should provide an empty vector as argument. After the call that vector will have been populated.
2. Use the vector you get as return value from the recursive call and concatenate it to the local vector

   ```cpp
   vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
       vector<int> nodesVal;
       if (root != nullptr) {            
           nodesVal.push_back(root->val);
           if (root->left) {
               vector<int> leftVals = preorderTraversal(root->left);
               nodesVal.insert(nodesVal.end(), leftVals.begin(), leftVals.end());
           }
           if (root->right) {
               vector<int> rightVals = preorderTraversal(root->right);
               nodesVal.insert(nodesVal.end(), rightVals.begin(), rightVals.end());
           }
       }
       return nodesVal;
   }
   ```

Comment: could you explain this sentence: the vector that is returned by the recursive call is ignored.

Comment: In your code, you have `preorderTraversal(root->left)`. That function call returns a vector, but you are not capturing that vector in a variable, so the reference to it is lost.

Comment: why is it that the vector nodesVal is ignored during Each of the recursive call? is it because nodesVal was created as a local variable? Or the real reason has to do with Recursion function get its own frame in the stack, so that's why each function call has its own nodesVal and they are not being shared by each of the recursive call? is that the reason? thanks

Comment: `nodesVal` is declared as a local variable, so every execution of the function has its own `nodesVal`. In your code, you *return* that `nodesVal` so that the caller *can* get access to it, but since the caller didn't do anything with that returned vector, it is lost.

Comment: But I thought my call to preOrderTraversal(root->left) would makes a call to nodesVal.push_back(root->val) which should then store the root->left 's val in the nodesVal vector? or this nodesVal is no longer the same nodesVal vector as the very original one nodesVal from the very very first call of the preORderTraversal function?

Comment: Like I said: each execution of the function has its own `nodesVal`. That `push_back` happens on that local `nodesVal`, and so in your code that **always** results in a vector with just that one element. These different `nodesVal` variables are distinct, local to the **execution** of the function. Each execution creates its own local variable. This is not so much related with recursion, but how the execution of any function sets the context of local variables it may define.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250473/discussion-between-trincot-and-hodondo).

Comment: thanks for the explanations. But could you explain why the line: printf("vector's value at position i:  %d\n", nodesVal[i]);      still produces a print output that would actually print the correct value of the sequence of the in-order traversal of that tree there in the example? for example it was able to correctly output the value at 0, 1 and 2 position in the vector nodesVal? Did it not produce the value nodesVal[0], nodesVal[1], nodesVal[2] correctly?

Comment: oh I see. But may I know in your 2nd code this part here: vector<int> leftVals = preorderTraversal(root->left);       is it correct that each recursive call will on hold at that line? until the next recursive call at that line has been finished (i.e. returned) then it will proceed afterwards? so the very first call to:     vector<int> leftVals = preorderTraversal(root->left); will have to wait till very very last recursive call is done, then it will get the leftVals vector and be inserted? so 1st recursive wait for 2nd to finish, but 2nd recursive must wait for 3rd recursive call?

Comment: so in the end 1st recursive call will not return until the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, .... nth recursive call has been returned? just like 2nd recursive call will be on hold and has to wait for the 3rd, 4th, 5th, ... nth to all return first before 2nd can proceed and finish its own call before returning to the 1st recursive call for the 1st recursive call to finish?

Comment: Please use the chat room.